# Databound project template Expression blend

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

What is Databound template in Expression Blend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a project template ready for development respecting the [Model-View-ViewModel pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). In short it separates the interface from the data and uses DataBinding to link them together.
The template creates the View and ViewModel folders.